# Not being able to size Google Map in UIView

Tags: swift, google-maps, uiview, subview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google Maps SKD and I'm trying to make a map fits in a `UIView`. Firstly, I've added a full screen `UIView` which displays a `GMSPanoramaView` in my app. It works great, here is variables declaration:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var streetViewer: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var gmapViewer: UIView!

 var panoView: GMSPanoramaView!
 var mapView: GMSMapView!
```

Then in `viewDiDLoad()` I create the panorama and add it as a subview of `streetViewer`:

```
 panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height))
 panoView.delegate = self
 panoView.moveNearCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.732, longitude: 150.312))
 streetViewer.addSubview(panoView)
 streetViewer.sendSubviewToBack(panoView)
```

Now I'm trying to do the same with a `UIView` which covers about half of the screen and displays `mapView` over the layer of `panoView`. So I create the map, add it as a subview of `gmapViewer` and finally add it too as a subview and move it on top of `panoView`:

```
 mapView = GMSMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, gmapViewer.bounds.size.width, gmapViewer.bounds.size.height))
 mapView.delegate = self
 gmapViewer.addSubview(mapView)
 streetViewer.addSubview(gmapViewer)
 panoView.sendSubviewToBack(gmapViewer)
```

I've added constrainst to all `UIView`. I've also added some paper folding animation to `gmapViewer` and all work great, apart from the map which does not fill `gmapViewer`. I think the problem stands in `mapView = GMSMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, gmapViewer.bounds.size.width, gmapViewer.bounds.size.height))` but I can't understand what does not work since it worked for `panoView`.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @MrMins i posted down here the code to do what i was trying to accomplish, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this after almost 5 years because it bugs me that this question is still without an answer, i think i improved enough a iOS programmer to be able to answer my own question and i hope this helps out someone else.

My mistake was that i messed out trying to mix constraints set programmatically and by storyboard, not sure why i didn't simply set mapView with frame `CGRect(gmapViewer.bounds.size.width/2, 0, gmapViewer.bounds.size.width/2, gmapViewer.bounds.size.height)`.

Anyway, the code down below displays a full screen Google Street View, covered by a half screen sized Google Map View.

```
private let mapView = GMSMapView()
private let streetView = GMSPanoramaView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(streetView)
    self.view.addSubview(mapView)
    streetView.moveNearCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.3317134, longitude: -122.0307466))
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    streetView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                              y: 0,
                              width: view.bounds.size.width,
                              height: view.bounds.size.height)
    mapView.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.size.width/2,
                           y: 0,
                           width: view.bounds.size.width/2,
                           height: view.bounds.size.height)
}
```